# How do I create a file with the iOS\Cocoa Touch\Objective-C class template in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

Forgive how simple this might sound but I'm stuck and need help. I am putting In App Purchases into may first app, which is not yet released. (So I'm very new)

I have been using a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich. I have just finished starting the Master Detail Application Template. Now it says I need to create a IAPHelper class which will be my class for the IAP the step I am on says to "create a file with the iOS\Cocoa Touch\Objective-C class template". However when I open Xcode and I select new project, I don't see this option. It has Single View Application etc.. the closest thing I see is Cocoa Touch Static Library.

Can someone tell me how I "create a file with the iOS\Cocoa Touch\Objective-C class template". I'm lost, do I do it from inside the Master Application Template? Or do I use some other template name like utility or empty application or Cocoa Touch Static Library? Or do I not have this in my version of Xcode? Or am I totally coming at this the wrong way? ahhhh!lol

I have Xcode 4.3.2

I know this is probably a no-brainer for some but not for me :(

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you inside your project and then you are checking this? There should be a new file option if your project is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current project you are working in, right click on a file and click "New File..." or go to File>New>File and then you will probably want a Objective-c class objection under Cocoa Touch

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in the same project which you have done till now. What you are trying to do is to create new project where as the tutorial is asking you to create new file. You have to do this in the same project which you are working on. In order to do that there is an option in file menu to add a new file to project.